# Using substitution in Pythhon with mysql cursor method

Tags: python, mysql

I have multiple databases named in a pattern.  Database names,

for example:  `house_1`, `house_2`, `house_2`

In my Python(2.7) script, a variable gets passed (house_id). That variable contains 1, 2 or 3, etc.

I need to be able to establish a connection to the appropriate database depending on the house_id.

Individually, this looks like:

```
house1_db = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="mypassword!", host="127.0.0.1", database="house_1")

cursor = house1_db.cursor
```

It seems really clumsy to me to do it this way.  I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent of string substitution.

So, script gets passed `house_id = 6`

And then:

```
house%d_db = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="mypassword!", host="127.0.0.1", database="house_%d") % house_id

cursor = house%d_db.cursor % house_id
```

I know the above examples with `%d` are wrong.  But I think it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish.  Maybe not.

I've been playing around with string substitution mainly, and am getting errors like:  "

> String Object has no attribute cursor".

Thanks in advance.  I know this is a vague question.  I'm getting rather frustrated with it!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass `db_name` to it.

Using `with` closes your `connection` and `cursor` automatically.(No need to close it explicitly like `conn.close()`, `cursor.close()` )

Try this,

```
def create_conn(db_name):
    return mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="mypassword!", host="127.0.0.1", database=db_name)

with create_conn('house_1') as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        ...
```

Comment: Hey!  Thanks!  Will give that a try!!